# Logic inside constructor

Tags: php, class, oop, design-patterns, constructor

Is it a good idea to have logic inside `__constructor`?

```
public class someClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //some logic here
    }
```

So far I thought that it is fine; however, [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4ijjea/your_comments_on_the_crud_tool/d2zpfno) suggests the opposite.

Comment: @AbraCadaver that was what I thought... If I am not mistaken on the context, OP advices not to do it.

Comment: _"Logic"_ could mean many things.  `if(!empty($_POST)) { //do stuff }` is logic I think.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yap, that's what it is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Barry [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37145146/727208), one of the reasons is related to unit-testing, but it's just a side-effect.

Let's take the worst case scenario: you have a "class", which only has a constructor (you probably have seen such examples). So ... why was it even written as a class? You cannot alter it's state, you cannot request it to perform any task and you have no way to check, that it did what you wanted. You could as well used a linear file and just included it. This is *just bad*.

Now for a more reasonable example: let's assume you have a class, which has some validation checks in the constructor and makes a new DB connection in it. And and then it also has some public methods for performing various tasks

The most obvious problem is the "makes a new DB connection" - there is no way to affect or prevent this operation from outside the class. And that new connection is going off to do who-knows-what (probably loading some configuration and trying to throw exceptions). It also constitutes a hidden dependency, for which you have no indication, without inspecting the class's code.

And there is a similar problem with code, that does validations and/or transformations of passed parameters. It constitutes hidden logic (and thus violating [PoLA](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment). It also makes your class harder to extend, because you probably will want to retain *some* of that validation functionality, while replacing other part. And you don't have that option. Because all of that code gets run whenever you crate a new instance.

**Bottom line** is this - logic in constructor is considered to be a "code smell". It's not a mortal sin (like using `eval()` on a global variable), but it's a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't a good idea for automated testing.  When testing you want to be able to "mock" objects that allow you to control the logic especially in terms of interfaces.  So if you place logic in the constructor then it is very hard to test as you must use the *real* object.

here is a fantastic talk with much more detail on why not to put logic in constructor (google tech talk by Misko Hevery)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0

Comment: But, for test you need DI, and DI can be implemented not only by `__construct` but also by `set` methods...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak  I agree, well somewhat agree, I still think the answer to this uestion is no.  Whilst it is possible it isn't *best* practice to put loads of logic in a constructor... a factory sure... but not a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is little bit unclear because i don't think that __construct is bad place to logic, the question is what kind of logic you have here? Some kind of logic can be placed in constructor but another must not be present in constructor. For example [Symfony Response](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Response.php#L196) - constructor contains logic, but this logic is necessary for this object, and this constructor doesn't make some implicit actions. This constructor doesn't print content to output or something else - so this is good example (as for me)...

Also it is important to understand what you object must to do, if it will be immutable object - constructor can have little bit another view...

Also it's important to follow SOLID and appropriate design pattern...

Comment: So, what is the logic that can be placed?